# Backup of data from Linux PC

Tags: ssh, backup

I have Linux PC, for which monitor is not working. But I am able to log in through SSH. I want to take a backup of all the directories from this PC. Instead of changing directories one by one and getting the files using FTP, is there any direct method to get all the files in the system at one time?

Comment: rsync can copy your whole system at once.

Comment: http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

Comment: There are a lot of options. Would this question be suitable for the software recommendation site?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Not at all. This is a “how to” question — essentially asking for something like `scp -r` (or better `rsync -ax`). Regarding suitability for [softwarerecs.se], please read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

Yes! you can use `lftp`, it is an ftp client that allows you to mirror a directory.
You can also use `scp -r` or as casey stated use `rsync`.